# iOS How can I access UIView property from UIViewController

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller

Can someone Please walk me through the steps because I feel a little stuck and lost

Previous question : [iOS - set UIButton target and action from its super class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17275819/ios-set-uibutton-target-and-action-from-its-super-class)

Now I'm trying to get a more general idea - I'm very new to this

Help is very appreciated

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to access the UIView of an associated UIViewController from inside the view controller itself, you simply use `self.view`. To access the same UIView from outside of the UIViewController class you would use the instance name of the class plus the `.view` property. For example:

```
//SomeClass.m
- (void)accessVCView
{
   //With a Nib File:
   MyUIViewController *aVCObject = [[MyUIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyNib" bundle:nil];
   //Or with a Storyboard:
   MyUIViewController *aVCObject = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"myStoryboard" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MyViewController"];

   UIView *myUIViewControllerView = aVCObject.view;
}
```